# How do I access failed redirects in react-native webview?

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview, plaid

Im using the Plaid Link Webview with React Native. The Webview works fine. The issue is Plaid uses redirects to communicate changes. I can't figure out how to access those redirects. I get a warning from react-native-webview saying `Cannot load url plaidlink://....` but I want to be able to read that URL. I've tried using `onNavigationStateChange` but that doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

My co-workers suggested this code:

```
<WebView
      source={{
        uri: `https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link.html?isWebview=true&token=${linkToken}`,
      }}
      originWhitelist={['https://*', 'plaidlink://*']}
      onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={handleNavigationStateChange}
    />
const handleNavigationStateChange = (event: any) => {
    if (event.url.startsWith('plaidlink://')) {
      console.log(event.url)
}
```

However, we'd also like to recommend using Plaid's official SDKs when possible, such as our [React Native SDK](https://github.com/plaid/react-native-plaid-link-sdk), rather than reading directly from Plaidlink URLs, as those URLs could change in the future.